# Find the correct option/s

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $|z-5+12i|\le1$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are the largest and the smallest values  of $|z|$. Then

## Options

$1.$ $|\alpha+i\beta|^2=340$

$2.$ $|\alpha-i\beta|^2=240$

$3.$ $\textrm{HCF}(\alpha,\beta)=4$

$4.$ $\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\beta}{4}=10$

---

My work
$$1\ge|z+(12i-5)|\ge|z|-|12i-5|$$
$$\implies 14\ge|z| \:\:\textrm{or}\:\: \alpha=14$$
Applying similar identities, I got the lower bound as $-12$ but it doesn't make any sense as modulus of a complex number can't be negative.

---

I then decided to approach it geometrically. I assumed $z=x+iy$ and then drew the shape on argand plane and tried to maximize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but in vain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.
You are on the right track.  From the triangle inequality we have

$$\begin{align}
 |z|&=|z-z_0+z_0|\\\\
&\le |z_0|+|z-z_0|\\\\
&\le |z_0|+1
\end{align}$$

and for $|z_0|\ge 1$ and $|z-z_0|\le 1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
|z|&=|z-z_0+z_0|\\\\
&\ge ||z_0|-|z-z_0||\\\\
&\ge |z_0|-1
\end{align}$$

So for $z_0=-5+i 12$, $|z_0|=13$. Then, the largest $|z|$ can be is $\alpha=13+1=14$, while the smallest $|z|$ can be is $\beta=13-1=12$.

Then, note that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=14^2+12^2=340$.  So, the answer is

$1.  |\alpha+i\beta|^2 = 340$

Comment: I can't understand why you did $+1$ and $-1$ in the above calculations. How did you get the lower bound.

Comment: Also, if $\alpha=14$ and $\beta=12$ then the last option should also be correct $?$

Comment: Let $w=z-z_0$, where $|z_0|\ge 1$.  The set of points for which $|w|\le 1$ lie on the closed disk $|z-z_0|\le 1$.  This is the unit disk in the $z$-plane with the center at $z_0$.  The farthest and closest points from the origin are along the line that connects $0$ and $z_0$.  And these points have distances $|z_0|+1$ and $|z_0|-1$.  And yes, $4$ works if $\alpha =14$ and $\beta=12$.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad I've edited to make the solution algebraic now.  And yes, $4.$ works too.